# Where does Google Flights get its pricing information?

Tags: datasets

I was wondering if anyone knows how I can get flight data in mass.  Specifically, I'm looking for price, time, and airports involved.

Do you know where Google, Expedia, and the likes get their flight information from?

Comment: Hi, Jay. Unfortunately, this question is not really on topic here at [aviation.se]. Questions about airline pricing will generally be better suited to [travel.se]. Also, questions that are just asking for a data source are usually not considered on topic on StackExchange sites.

Comment: no problem I'll refrain from here on out.  Thanks for clearing that up.  I became skeptical once my questions weren't popping up in the Previously Asked column

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Google bought an airline pricing optimization 
company called ITA Software that has interfaces with the GDS systems.

Comment: cool, thanks! hh